# Is there any tool available to parse mysql binlog file in row format and create json

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysqlbinlog

I have mysql binlog enabled in row format.
I am using mysqlbinlog to parse binlog file.
I am using this command:

```
 mysqlbinlog --base64-output=decode-rows -vv ./mysql-bin.000004
```

This command returns sql statements that I have to parse to generate json.

I used pymysqlreplication module in python but it doesn't read from binlog file. It requires real-time mysql replication connection. I can't access archived binlog files using master server.

Is there any way to parse archived binlog file and generate json?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [binlog-parser](https://github.com/zalora/binlog-parser).

> A tool for parsing a MySQL binlog file to JSON. Reads a binlog input file, queries a database for field names, writes JSON to stdout.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
https://github.com/noplay/python-mysql-replication
```

This is used by several independent projects as mentioned on their page.

I have created a separate binlog parser based on sqlparse(python). The link to that :

```
https://github.com/monothorn/mysql-parser
```